# Rails 4.2 complex associations with condition in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to display simple red dot above envelope icon if user has unreaded message in his all conversations. I do not have idea how to do it.

**_header.html.erb**

```
<% if current_user.messages.exists?(read: false) %>  
  <%= link_to conversations_path do %>
    <div id='topbar-notification-bubble-container'>
      <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
      <div class="notification-bubble"></div>
   </div>  
   <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to conversations_path do %>
    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**conversation.rb**

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, :foreign_key => :sender_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, :foreign_key => :recipient_id, class_name: 'User'

  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy

  validates_uniqueness_of :sender_id, :scope => :recipient_id

  scope :between, -> (sender_id, recipient_id) do
    where("(conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id =?) OR (conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id = ?)", sender_id, recipient_id, recipient_id, sender_id)
  end
end
```

**message.rb**

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :body, :conversation_id, :user_id

  def message_time
    created_at.strftime("%d.%m.%Y. u %H:%M")
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :products, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments
  has_many :purchases, foreign_key: :buyer_id
  has_many :purchases, foreign_key: :seller_id
  has_many :notifications
  has_many :conversations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy

  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :large => "250x250#", :thumb => "65x65#" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  acts_as_voter

end
```

**conversations controller**

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @users = User.all
    @conversations = Conversation.all
  end

  def create
    if Conversation.between(params[:sender_id], params[:recipient_id]).present?
      @conversation = Conversation.between(params[:sender_id], params[:recipient_id]).first
    else
      @conversation = Conversation.create!(conversation_params)
    end
    redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
  end

  private

    def conversation_params
      params.permit(:sender_id, :recipient_id)
    end
end
```

**messages controller**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  before_action do
    @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
  end

  def index
    @messages = @conversation.messages
    if @messages.length > 10
      @over_ten = true
      @messages = @messages[-10..-1]
    end
    if params[:m]
      @over_ten = false
      @messages = @conversation.messages
    end

    @messages.each do |message|
      if message.user_id != current_user.id
        message.update_attribute(:read, true)
      end
    end

    @message = @conversation.messages.new
  end

  def new
    @message = @conversation.messages.new
  end

  def create
    @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params)
    if @message.save
      redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
    end
  end

  private

    def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:body, :user_id)
    end
end
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. It looks like you've got an example already in `_header.html.erb` - can you tell us what is wrong with that example? ie what do you expect to see, and what are you seeing instead? If you already have the classes set up in CSS, then can you include the CSS? Can you show us the html that is output in each of the two situations? (messages and no messages)? Perhaps set up a css-fiddle for us to play with?

Comment: Thanks for interest. Problem is with IF conditional logic in _header.html.erb. This code checks only current user messages, and when current user sends message to other user, current user gets red bubble (for unread message) because when message is created it has status :read = false. Message has user_id of someone who created it. I want this outcome: conditional checks all current user conversations, then checks all messages (but not with current user id!) in previous conversations, and at the end checks read: false? CSS is not relevant. If you need more info just tell me.

Comment: you have just verbally described the code that you have already provided. This is not helpful. What happened when you ran the code you already have? what did you see? did you see the red bubble? if not why not? CSS most definitely *is* relevant, as it is what displays the red bubble. If you have no CSS, then no red bubble. what I mean by "what did you see instead" is "when you ran the rails server and looked at the page for a user that has an unread message, did you see the red bubble? if not, what did you see instead? what html was rendered?"

Comment: Now I'm not getting any error. But the current user (after sending new message) has a red bubble, and user that received new message does not have red bubble. It should be opposite.

Comment: Well, then, that's easy to fix - just reverse the conditional :)

Comment: No errors, but now all users have red bubble, although all messages are read: true.

Comment: Yes... so your conditional is backwards... and you should negate it so that they get he bubble only when all-read is not true.